# IPN - tutorial has errors

Tags: php, paypal

I was trying to follow the tutorial on paypal's developer site on setting up a basic IPN listener, and it looks nearly syntax for syntax like on their example. In fact when I started receiving the errors I've been receiving, I thought I would create a new ipn listener and use just the code they have in their example to see if it was my code or not and received the same errors.

```
Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in \supergate\ipn.php on line 42

Warning: feof(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in \supergate\ipn.php on line 39
```

the errors on those line numbers are for these pieces of code at those lines:

```
 while (!feof($fp)) //line 39
{

 $res = fgets($fp, 1024); //line 42
```

here is the rest of the entire code

```
<?php
//Empty Header HTTP 200 OK reponse to ack receipt of the notification
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//assign payment notification values to local variables
$item_name        =$_POST['item_name'];
$item_number       =$_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status    =$_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_ammount   =$_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency  =$_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id            =$_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email    =$_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email       =$_POST['payer_email'];
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//build the required ack message of notification just received
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; //add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of acknowledgement

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  //loop through the notification nv pairs
  $value = urlencode(stripcslashes($value)); //encode these values
 $req .= "&$key=$value"; //add the nv pairs to the acknowledgement
}

//set up the acknowledgement request headers

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n"; //HTTP POST REQUEST
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Content-Length: " .strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

//send the http post request back to paypal for validation
fputs($fp, $header . $req);

while (!feof($fp)) 
{

    $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
    {
     //WRITE TO EMAIL


    */
 }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 else if (strcmp($res,"INVALID") == 0) 
 {

   //write to email
}


fclose($fp); //close the file
?>
```

Okay now the new warning I get is this:

```
Warning: fgets() [function.fgets]: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the result of [`fsockopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) which returns `FALSE` upon failure.

```
$fp = fsockopen(...);
if ($fp === FALSE) {
    exit("Could not open socket");
}
```

---

One clue from the documentation is the first parameter:

> **hostname**
>   If OpenSSL support is installed, you may prefix the hostname with either ssl:// or tls:// to use an SSL or TLS client connection over TCP/IP to connect to the remote host.

Note that your example is using `ssl://` - it is possible your server is not correctly configured with OpenSSL.